# ReferenceError: FlatListItemSeparator is not defined in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist, react-flatlist

I'm new to React Native, and I'm following along with an online tutorial.
This is my `App.js` file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {View,Text,ImageBackground,FlatList, Image, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import bookmarkIcon from './assets/bookmark.png';
import readIcon from './assets/read.png';
import styles from './styles';

const ArticleItem = ({article}) => {
  const { title, description, url, urlToImage } = article;
  return (
    <View style = { styles.articleContainer }>
      <Image style={ styles.articleImage } source={{ uri: urlToImage }} />
      <Text style= { styles.articleTitle }>
        { title }
      </Text>
      <Text style = { styles.articleDescription }>
        { description }
      </Text>
      <View style = { styles.articleBtns}>
        <IconButton width= "50%" color = "white" bgcolor = "#ff5c5c" icon = { readIcon } onPress = { () => { console.log("Button pressed!")} } title = "Open" />
        <IconButton width= "50%" color = "white" bgcolor = "#ff5c5c" icon = { bookmarkIcon } onPress = { () => { console.log("Button pressed!")} } title = "Read later" />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: 1,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "#000",
      }}
    />
  );
}

FlatListHeader = () => {
  return (
    <View elevation={1} 
      style={{
        height: 100,
        width: "97%",
        margin: 5,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        border: 2.9,
        borderColor: "black",
        alignSelf: "center",
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 16,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 1,
        shadowRadius: 7.49
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{
          textShadowColor: 'black',
          textShadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 3 },
          textShadowRadius: 10,
          fontSize: 40,
          fontWeight: '800',
          flex: 1,
          alignSelf: "center",
          paddingTop: 30
          }}
          >Latest articles</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const IconButton = ({title, color, bgcolor, onPress, width, icon }) =>{
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress = { onPress } style= { { flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: bgcolor } }>
    <View style={ {width: width, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' } }>
      <Image style = { { height: 27, width:27, margin : 5 } } source = {  icon }></Image>
      <Text style = { {color: color }} > { title } </Text>      
    </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

const HomeScreen = (props) => {
  console.log("articles: ", props.articles);
  return (
    <View>
        <FlatList
          data={ props.articles }
          ListHeaderComponent = { this.FlatListHeader }   
          ItemSeparatorComponent = { this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({item}) => <ArticleItem article = { item }  />}
        />
    </View>
  );
}

const SplashScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style = { styles.container } >
    <ImageBackground  style= { styles.backgroundImage } source={{uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/IGlBYaC.jpg'}} >
            
      <View style= { styles.logoContainer }>
        <Text style = { styles.logoText }>
          Newzzz
        </Text>
        <Text style = { styles.logoDescription }>
          Get your doze of daily news!
        </Text>
        
      </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
} 

const App = () => {
  const URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nimramubashir/React-Native/fetch/articles.json';
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(URL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.articles;
    })
    .then( articles  => {
      setArticles(articles);
      console.log(articles);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
    
  } , []);
  
  if (loading){
      return <SplashScreen />
    } else {
      return <HomeScreen articles = { articles }/>
  }
};

export default App
```

The code is the same as the tutorial, but when I'm trying to run this code, I'm getting an Error

> ReferenceError: FlatListItemSeparator is not defined

I've tried to import the `FlatListItemSeparator`, but since it is read-only, I can't. I'm getting this error at both FlatListItemSeparator and FlatListHeader. Why am I getting this error, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

you are having each component as separate Function-Component. The tutorial is probably based on Class-Components. In Function-Components there is no `this`, so just remove the `this.`

Comment: The error is now removed from the FlatListHeader = () =>  and now it is showing at  FlatListHeader at  ``` ListHeaderComponent = { FlatListHeader }   
          ItemSeparatorComponent = { FlatListItemSeparator} ```  instead

Comment: but you removed the `this.` there as well? Ah and you should put a const before the Function if you use the = () => notation.